Is there a way in Groovy to intercept a static method call, a la invokeMethod, that would be inherited by a subclass?
I'm trying to find a way to quietly wrap the main method of a class in a try/catch block.
What I'm imagining is a static version of invokeMethod, where I can simply intercept the main method call and wrap it in my superclass:
@Log4j2
class Wrapper {
  static def invokeMethod(String name,args) {
    if(name == 'main') {
      def main = subclass.&main  // Unsure how I would get the subclass.
      try {
        main(args)
      } catch(any) {
        log.error("An unhandled exception was thrown.",any)
      }
    } else {
      def fun = subclass.&"$name"
      fun(args)
    }
  }
}

class Main extends Wrapper {
  static void main(args) {
    throw new Exception("This should be logged.")
  }
}

Upon execution, assuming I've configured Log4j2 properly, the Exception would be logged.
Is there a way to accomplish this without writing code directly to the subclass's main method definition?

problem with this idea - you can't override static methods... why not to put all the code you have in Wrapper.invokeMethod into Wrapper.main that will just call Main.main inside try-catch?
